# How to prevent WCF service from wrapping CDATA in response?

Tags: c#, wcf, postman, rest-client

I have created WCF method which return C# object as response. Now the problem is that while I am posting request to this method using chrome postman I am getting JSON response and some of parameters are wrapped with CDATA. For example, One of parameter URL has value like "http://www.examplewebsite.com/CDATA[SomeValue".

Any solution to prevent wrapping of CDATA ? Or wrapping this URL value like "CDATA[http://www.examplewebsite.com/SomeValue]" ?